# Rolling Correlation of Time Series Data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, correlation, rolling-computation

Below is a small sample of my data. I have some values at certain times, labelled A, that I want to correlate with prices at certain times, labelled B.

Each A Value considers the interval up until the corresponding time. The value 0.054873437864689699 is from midnight to 651.0 minutes (or 10:51am). The value 0.055546509015723597 is from 651.0 to 653.0 minutes (or 10:51am to 10:53am) and so on.

Each B Value is a price at a corresponding time accurate to the millisecond. I can simply average the prices over an interval to match the times with the A values.

I found "rolling_corr_pairwise" in the Pandas documentation. I am completely new to Pandas and need a super simplified, step by step explanation of how to implement this. Making a DataFrame is also new to me. I want to find and graph a rolling correlation of the A and B values with time in, say, a 50 minute window. I realize the way the times are listed (minutes from midnight) is terrible, so thank you for bearing with me.

## A-Values to be correlated

[0.054873437864689699, 0.055546509015723597, 0.056806870789744064, 0.05656315835834981, 0.056307375921714732, 0.056614971519205935, 0.058407075702340799, 0.058483089024092987, 0.059124318881877719, 0.057917622539541552, 0.058499741855677162, 0.059480023024158751, 0.059925414031410718, 0.059699384112206717, 0.059783470585893353, 0.058500193498812712, 0.056660594185120206, 0.057215267146834899, 0.054616609322569204, 0.053707026223574213, 0.053727363037656489, 0.052396419451433848, 0.051417634891722949, 0.050305835255857634, 0.050611614412277413, 0.050005571241158321, 0.051123891272704211, 0.049674112051554621, 0.049446781886845974, 0.047887309892200268]

## A-Times in minutes since midnight

[651.0, 653.0, 656.0, 657.0, 658.0, 661.0, 663.0, 665.0, 666.0, 668.0, 671.0, 673.0, 674.0, 675.0, 676.0, 677.0, 679.0, 680.0, 682.0, 683.0, 684.0, 686.0, 687.0, 689.0, 691.0, 693.0, 696.0, 700.0, 701.0, 704.0]

## B-Prices, to be correlated with A

[116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.32, 116.32, 116.32, 116.32, 116.32, 116.32, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.3201, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.3201, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33, 116.33]

## B-Times in minutes since midnight of the prices, where 1 millisecond = minute/60000

[629.5010833333333, 629.5010833333333, 629.5013166666666, 629.5013166666666, 629.5013166666666, 629.5018166666666, 629.5047, 629.507, 629.5070666666667, 629.5071166666667, 629.508, 629.508, 629.508, 629.508, 629.508, 629.5080333333333, 629.5080666666667, 629.5080666666667, 629.5080666666667, 629.5080666666667, 629.5080666666667, 629.5081, 629.5081833333334, 629.5081833333334, 629.5082166666666, 629.50865, 629.50865, 629.5087166666667, 629.5093166666667, 629.5098333333333, 629.5195, 629.5197, 629.5240166666666, 629.5316333333333, 629.5316666666666, 629.5316666666666, 629.5316666666666, 629.5316666666666, 629.5316666666666, 629.5316666666666, 629.5317666666666, 629.5317666666666, 629.5317666666666, 629.5317666666666, 629.5317666666666, 629.5317666666666, 629.5320333333333, 629.5325, 629.5325333333333, 629.5365833333333]

Comment: if you're going to ask a question about pandas, it's courteous to potential "answerers" to include some basic startup code to get your data into a pandas structure (e.g., DataFrame, Panel)

Comment: It would behoove you to study the docs and many tutorials to get an introduction to pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html.